# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis - only comes up when I add a where statement (

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am using a string to access a code that will then access an ORACLE data, I use this code a lot, but for some reason it is not working now.  The code below works fine when I don't include a where statement, but gives the above error when I do.  I have looked at other examples of this error, but can not find any that match what I am doing.  Any help would be appreciated.  Start year is the number 2010

```
 select * from(
    select  
        count(distinct(fileid)) as cyic,
        to_number(substr(cym, 1, 4)) as cym,
    from group.data
    group by fileid, cym
    where to_number(substr(cym, 1, 4)) >= :start_yr
)
```

Comment: You have an extra `,` after `as cym`

Comment: Why do you need the outer `select * from ...`?

Comment: Plus, the WHERE clause should come before GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `WHERE` clause must come before the `GROUP BY` clause. If you need to check something after the grouping, then you use `HAVING` after the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe it was that simple, I was trying everything, but apparently not that.